# Integral of addition of measurable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f,g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ (extended real line) be measurable functions.

Prove that if both $\int f^{+} d\mu$ and $\int g^{+} d\mu$ are finite, or both $\int f^{-} d\mu$ and $\int g^{-} d\mu$ are finite, then

$\int (f+g) d\mu = \int f d\mu + \int g d\mu$.

We have a known result stating that that the above result works for integrals in the interval $[0, \infty]$, so if I can show that

$(f + g) + f^{-} + g^{-} \ge 0$ then my result should follow?